# Apply model metadata on complex objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelmetadata

I have the following scenario

```
public class Foo {
    public Bar FooBar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    [DisplayFormatAttribute(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I use EditorFor I want to apply the DataFormatString on my DateTime

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FooBar.BirthDay);
```

The above code does not render the date correct using the DisplayFormatAttribute, so how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have to use this i think.

```
public class Bar {
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat( DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true )]
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
}
```

OR you can use like this

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
```

in your view, you can try this.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FoorBar.BirthDay.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Comment: This is the result 7/11/2012 12:00:00 AM

Comment: why dont you try html.TextBoxFor instead of html.EditodFor ... i am sure this works for TextBoxFor

Comment: No it doesn't same exception with that one